# Bind9 dns server logging options (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: dns, log

I want to create a separate file for my DNS server (`bind9`) to write log.
I found some info on how to do it on the [Ubuntu community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto#Logging).

So I added these lines to `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`:

```bsh
logging {
    channel query.log {
        file "/var/log/query.log";
        // Set the severity to dynamic to see all the debug messages.
        severity dynamic;
    };
};
```

I went on to create a log file, gave all permissions to it and restarted `bind9` service and when checked the status I saw an error:

```
cd /var/log
touch query.log
chmod 777 query.log
systemctl restart bind9
systemctl status bind9
```

```
● bind9.service - BIND Domain Name Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bind9.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-04-02 17:37:24 UTC; 1s ago
     Docs: man:named(8)
  Process: 5723 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rndc stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4480 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/rndc reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5851 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -f $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5851 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 02 17:37:24 ballgame named[5851]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Apr 02 17:37:24 ballgame named[5851]: configuring command channel from '/etc/bind/rndc.key'
Apr 02 17:37:24 ballgame named[5851]: isc_stdio_open '/var/log/query.log' failed: permission denied
Apr 02 17:37:24 ballgame named[5851]: command channel listening on ::1#953
Apr 02 17:37:24 ballgame named[5851]: isc_stdio_open '/var/log/query.log' failed: permission denied
Apr 02 17:37:24 ballgame named[5851]: configuring logging: permission denied
Apr 02 17:37:24 ballgame named[5851]: loading configuration: permission denied
Apr 02 17:37:24 ballgame named[5851]: exiting (due to fatal error)
Apr 02 17:37:24 ballgame systemd[1]: bind9.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 02 17:37:24 ballgame systemd[1]: bind9.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Can someone explain me what is missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
~# grep log /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named
  # some people like to put logs in /var/log/named/ instead of having
  # syslog do the heavy lifting.
  /var/log/named/** rw,
  /var/log/named/ rw,
```

Logs should be in `/var/log/named/` or Apparmor will silently deny access. If you *REALLY* want to override the package maintainer's choices, configure it in `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named`

Comment: Finally the answer ! Thank you Waddles :]

Answer (score 0):

Bumped to the same issue when uncommented logging section in named.conf.

As @Waddles suggested it's AppArmor.
Probably missing permissions for /var/log/*

- make logging to folder like /var/log/bind/
- make bind user owner of folder
- check and change (if needed) ...

  $ sudo vi /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named

Find following section

```
  /etc/bind/** r,
  /var/lib/bind/** rw,
  /var/lib/bind/ rw,
  /var/cache/bind/** lrw,
  /var/cache/bind/ rw,
```

And, immediately after the last line in that block (/var/cache/bind/ rw,), add:

```
  /var/log/bind/** rw,
  /var/log/bind/ rw,
```

Save the file and exit, then reload AppArmor:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apparmor
```

Then start bind again and error should be gone.